# What's the meaning of "the interpreter inserts a newline before it prints the next prompt if the last line was not completed."

Tags: python

I learn Python by reading The Python Tutorial of python.org. When I read the third chapter:[3. An Informal Introduction to Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html), I can't understand the last sentence of the article which is "the interpreter inserts a newline before it prints the next prompt if the last line was not completed." Does somebody know what it is meaning? It is better if there is an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each time you use a `print` statement that ends in a comma, the interpreter sets a flag to remember that it *didn't* write a newline yet.

Because putting the next prompt on the same line as those numbers would be inconvenient (it won't be in the left-most column as you expect it to be), Python will write a newline character so that the prompt ends up in the left column again; it uses that flag set by the `print` statement to detect this situation.

So instead of getting this in your interactive session:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 >>>
```

you see this:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
>>>
```

Interestingly enough, in Python 3 no such flag is set anymore because `print()` is now a function. As a result, the interactive interpreter can no longer detect this situation and puts the prompt right after the numbers:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.4.2 (default, Feb 10 2015, 10:25:29) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)]'
>>> a, b = 0, 1
>>> while b < 1000:
...     print(b, end=',')
...     a, b = b, a+b
... 
1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't happen:

```
>>> a, b = 0, 1
>>> while b < 1000:
...     print b,
...     a, b = b, a+b
...
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 >>> (prompt here)
```

Instead, this happens:

```
>>> a, b = 0, 1
>>> while b < 1000:
...     print b,
...     a, b = b, a+b
...
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
>>> (prompt here, after a newline)
```

Even though the line was never really "completed": any following `print x,` statements would've continued it.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial that you are referring to, uses the following snippet as an example

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 1000:
    print b,
    a, b = b, a+b
```

The sentence that is unclear to you refers to how the line ends after the final print. A comma tells the interpreter that there is no newline on the current line, which can easily be visualized by doing something like this

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 1000:
    print b,
    a, b = b, a+b
print "Look where I am"
```

This will print that final statement on the same line as your numbers, like this

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 Look where I am
```

Now adding another print below the previous one (that has no comma, therefore it does have a new line), you will see that the new statement will be printed below the *Look where I am* statement

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 1000:
    print b,
    a, b = b, a+b
print "Look where I am"
print "And me"
```

This yields the following output

```
 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 Look where I am
 And me
```